# Cannot get JSON from Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, parse-error

I am writing an application and I cannot get the JSON using Ajax. Or better, when using XAMPP locally it works correctly, but it doesn't when I upload everything on my domain. What's wrong? PHP seems to work fine, I just get the error function instead of success.

```
function groupGetDocsList() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '../php/group_docs_list.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            docsList = $.parseJSON(data);
            for(var i = 0; i < docsList.length; i++) {
                docsListNames[i] = docsList[i].replace(/_/g, ' ').replace('.html', '');
            }
            groupSearchDocs();
        },
        error: function(data) {
            $('#group-docs-list-found').append('No documents found.');
            $('#group-docs-list').append('Error loading documents.');
        }
    });
}
```

Also without `$.parseJSON` it isn't working.

The console shows this (that is not for my code I suppose since it appears simply including the jQuery javascript):

```
event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.
```

The status code is `200` and I get a `parseerror`.
I have validated my JSON code with many online validators: they all validate it correctly except for one, but I cannot understand why. It blocks itself on a parenthesis `(`.

```
["BMC_Bioinformatics_2008_Oct_1_9_406_ver1.html","BMC_Bioinformatics_2008_Oct_2_9_407_ver1.html","BMC_Cardiovasc_Disord_2002_Mar_27_2_7_ver1.html","BMC_Cardiovasc_Disord_2003_Feb_6_3_2_ver1.html","BMC_Cardiovasc_Disord_2005_Aug_19_5_24_ver1.html","BMC_Cardiovasc_Disord_2005_Aug_25_5_25_ver1.html","BMC_Cardiovasc_Disord_2008_Dec_18_8_39_ver1.html","BMC_Geriatr_2004_Jul_2_4_5_ver1.html","BMC_Geriatr_2004_Oct_15_4_9_ver1.html","BMC_Geriatr_2006_Jan_27_6_3_ver1.html","BMC_Geriatr_2006_Jul_31_6_9_ver1.html","BMC_Geriatr_2007_Dec_19_7_29_ver1.html","BMC_Geriatr_2008_Aug_17_8_19_ver1.html","BMC_Med_Genet_2007_Mar_22_8_13_ver1.html","BMC_Med_Genet_2007_May_30_8_28_ver1.html","BMC_Med_Genet_2009_Jan_30_10_9_ver1.html","BMC_Ophthalmol_2008_Aug_17_8_15_ver1.html","BMC_Pediatr_2003_Sep_4_3_10_ver1.html","BMC_Pediatr_2004_Aug_7_4_15_ver1.html","BMC_Pediatr_2004_Aug_31_4_16_ver1.html","BMC_Pediatr_2004_Dec_14_4_24_ver1.html","BMC_Pediatr_2004_Feb_11_4_3_ver1.html","BMC_Pediatr_2004_Jul_8_4_12_ver1.html","BMC_Pediatr_2004_Sep_1_4_17_ver1.html","BMC_Pediatr_2005_Dec_5_5_45_ver1.html","BMC_Pediatr_2005_Jun_28_5_19_ver1.html","BMC_Pediatr_2005_Nov_9_5_40_ver1.html","BMC_Pediatr_2005_Sep_21_5_38_ver1.html","Breast_Cancer_Res_2005_Jul_27_7(**5)_R775-R779_ver1.html"**,
"Breast_Cancer_Res_2005_Jun_16_7(5)_R669-R680_ver1.html"
**]**
```

The 2 pieces of code between ** and ** at the end of the JSON is where the validator fails and returns the following errors:

```
Error:Expecting object or array, not number.[Code 3, Structure 2]
Error:Strings should be wrapped in double quotes.[Code 17, Structure 3]
Error:Expecting ), after ].[Code 2, Structure 6]
Error:Extra closing ][Code 14, Structure 6]
```

It is sufficient to delete the `(` before the `5` in the penultimate string and the JSON is correctly validated.

I have checked many times the URL path, it's correct. The PHP code is this:

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    $fileToString = file_get_contents('../documents/');
    $stringToArray = preg_match_all('/[(A-Za-z0-9_\-)]+.html(?=<)/', $fileToString, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
    $jsonDic = json_encode($matches[0]);
    echo $jsonDic;
?>
```

If opening this file, it correctly prints the json.

Comment: no need to use `$.parseJSON` when `dataType` is set to `json`. jQuery will do it internally. Sounds like a path problem. Inspect request itself in browser console/dev tools. Can see status, what is sent and what is returned( if anything)

Comment: where is your PHP code?

Comment: did you have a look at the console? (chromes developer console, or firefox Firebug extension)

Comment: @user3666575 Are you getting 404 error?

Comment: Parseerror means that jQuery cannot parse the JSON. Check whether your php file contains a BOM or any other strange character that makes the response invalid JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, check your URL path. It's a red flag to me that there is .. at the beginning. Next, as the other commenters said, use the browser console to see any errors or if the request was made successfully.

Comment: You were right! It was the URL path which needs to be relative to the page where the function is called and not where the function is. Thank you very much!